# Using Server.MapPath to save a file

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

At the moment, I am saving my file to a directory hard coded in my code:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\users\my documents\github\project\source\project\App_Data\stored\", package.Id + ".zip");
```

But I need to save my file using Server.MapPath ....
Like:

```
FileInfo userFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/stored"), package.Id));
```

The complete function:

```
 public void CompressAndDeleteSources(FlinkeMailPackage package)
 {
    var filePath = Path.Combine(@"C:\users\my documents\github\project\source\project\App_Data\stored\", package.Id + ".zip");

    using (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(filePath))
    {
      foreach (var file in package.FlinkeMailFileList)
      {               
        string bestandsNaam = @"C:\users\my documents\github\project\source\project\App_Data\uploads\" + file.OriginalName;
        zipFile.AddFile(bestandsNaam);
      }
       zipFile.Save();
    }

    foreach (var file in package.FlinkeMailFileList)
     {
         var filePathToDelete = @"C:\users\my documents\github\project\source\project\App_Data\uploads\" + file.FileName;
         File.Delete(filePathToDelete);
     }       
   }
```

But when I am trying to use `Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/stored")` it doesn't know what server is

**EDIT**

I can use it like:  `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/stored");`
But i can't use `package.Id + ".zip"` with it like example:  `var savePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/stored"),package.Id + ".zip"));`

Comment: `Server.MapPath` will map path to your application root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access it through the current context  `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/stored");`

to get the full file path :

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/stored"), package.Id + ".zip");
```

Comment: Ok, how can i use , package.Id + ".zip" with it. I can't use it like: var savePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/stored"), package.Id + ".zip"));

Answer (score -1):

```
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            if (fileName != "")
            {

                FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("../../Files/" + fileName));
                aComplain.FileName = fileName;
                aComplain.FilePath = "../../Files/" + fileName;

                string message = aComplainManager.SaveComplain(aComplain);
                messageResult.Text = message;
                messageResult.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                Clear();
            }

            else if (fileName == "")
            {
                string message = aComplainManager.SaveComplain(aComplain);
                messageResult.Text = message;
                messageResult.ForeColor = Color.Green;
                Clear();
            }
```